# Exceeds block gas limit while deploying the contract in latest ethereum

Tags: ethereum

I am trying to execute the steps from https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2.

However, the difference is I am running geth on AWS server instead of truffle or testnet as specified in the link. I need to get deployed contract address to try on UI. I am using the following geth command: `geth --networkid 12312423 --port 30303 -rpc -rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" -rpcport 8080 --rpcapi "web3,db,net,personal,eth" --rpccorsdomain "*" --preload mining.js --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --datadir=~/eth/data231 init genesis.json console`

I have run Node commands on another screen in the same machine. I have gone till the end of the steps and I am receiving Error: exceeds block gas limit while deploying the contract. Is there any error in the genesis.json that I am using.

Any suggestions will help thanks...

genesis.json

```
{
            "config": {
                "chainId": 15,
                "homesteadBlock": 0,
                "eip155Block": 0,
                "eip158Block": 0
            },
            "difficulty": "200000000",
            "gasLimit": "2100000",
            "alloc": {
                "7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82": { "balance": "300000" },
                "f41c74c9ae680c1aa78f42e5647a62f353b7bdde": { "balance": "400000" }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you quickly check the ether balances of account that is being used to deploy the contract ?  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts  . Look for check account balance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. There are 2 learnings from the solution:

1. The gasLimit in the genesis.json should be higher like "gasLimit": "3141592000000".
2. We should first start geth without init. Create account, unlock. Then allocate the balance for the account as below and do git init.
   i.e.
   Once you’ve generated your account, quit geth with and remove every folder except keystore/ from your datatir:
   $ cd 
   $ rm -rf `ls | grep -v keystore`
   update your genesis block json, adding the following to the alloc key:
   "alloc": {
   "": {
       "balance": "10000000000000000000"
   }
   }

Comment: You usually should get ```gasLimit``` value from the existing network or configure your own in terms of the private chain.  Here is a recent overview how to setup a private chain: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/private-network. Personally, I has migrated my private chain from ```ethash``` to ```clique``` consensus algorithm and start to get this error. Gas limit remained the same.